# ¿En Javascript cómo puedo eliminar las comas en un array al realizar el proceso de mostrar el resultado en un alert?

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, push, alert

En este código no consigo hacer desaparecer las comas al mostrar la tabla de multiplicar por un alert... Entiendo que con esto [" "] le digo a Javacript que existe un espacio vacío allí dentro del array y entonces lo toma como un elemento aparte y entonces coloca las comas, y para que un array se inicie vacío es solo [ ], pero aún así aparecen las comas... lo probé con console.log y las comas no aparecen, pero no sé si será solo tema de que es el comportamiento del prompt en sí o es el salto de línea al final /n

```
let numeroMultiplicar = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un número para mostrar su tabla de multiplicación"));
let tabla = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
let resultado = numeroMultiplicar * i;
tabla.push(`${numeroMultiplicar} X ${i} = ${resultado}\n`);
            }
alert(tabla);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado, no es el salto de linea el problema, lo que pasa es que al imprimir un arreglo estás imprimiendo la cadena completa, incluye comas e incluso las comillas (que el alert no las detecta). Entonces te muestro un ejemplo de como poder recorrer tu objeto pero solo los elementos para que puedas visualizarlo.

```js
let numeroMultiplicar = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un número para mostrar su tabla de multiplicación"));
let tabla = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  let resultado = numeroMultiplicar * i;
  tabla.push(`${numeroMultiplicar} X ${i} = ${resultado} \n`);
}

  alert(tabla.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `join()` para quitar las comas

```
alert(tabla.join(''));
```

La coma en el array funciona como un separador. Por ejemplo

```
let arr = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']
```

Al usar `join()` puedes quitar las comas o reemplazarlas por cualquier caracter.